# Keep ng-model in array and set values using loop AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, ngmodel

**Scenario**

I have scenario where I will parse the document then I will get as a JSON output in key and value format, In key it will contains headings of document and Value will contains corresponding section of the heading.  Now I would like to bind the values into ng-model (text boxes in forms), I have 100+ textboxes , I may get different headings from document, if I am getting different headings I like to bind into ng-model with or condition like below code.

**Requirement**

I like to store all my ng-model names into array 
for eg:

```
var array = [$scope.FirstNgModel,$scope.SecondNgModel,$scope.ThirdNgModel,$scope.FourthNgModel,$scope.FifthNgModel]
```

then I will read the exact matching and I will map.

Current code is below

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    var docparsed = JSON.parse(response);
    //angular.forEach($scope.ModelMaping, function (obj) {
    angular.forEach(docparsed, function (obj) {
        //var ModelVal = obj.value;
        //var val = docparsed.find(x => x.key.toLocaleLowerCase() === ModelVal.toLocaleLowerCase())
        //obj.key = val.value;   
        if (obj.key.toLocaleLowerCase() == "first") {
            $scope.FirstNgModel = obj.value;
        }
        if (obj.key.toLocaleLowerCase() == "second") {

            $scope.SecondNgModel = obj.value;
        }
        if (obj.key.toLocaleLowerCase() == "third") {
            $scope.ThirdNgModel = obj.value;
        }
        if (obj.key.toLocaleLowerCase() == "fourth") {
            $scope.FourthNgModel = obj.value;
        }
        if ((obj.key.toLocaleLowerCase() == "fifth") || (obj.key.toLocaleLowerCase() == "sixth")) {
            $scope.FifthNgModel = obj.value;
        }
    });
```

[Sample project](https://plnkr.co/edit/eGAdUw?p=info)

Comment: You can store parsed data into some ngModel, then you can create your form based on ngModal binding into the view using ng-repeat

Comment: Or else you have to create 100+ number of variables, Pls help me understand more

Comment: I am storing parsed values into array(as key value pairs), I wanted to assign the parsed values into ng-model.

Comment: angular.forEach($scope.test2, function (obj) {
       var the_string = obj;
        var model = $parse(the_string);
        model.assign($scope, 42);
        //console.log($scope.First);
     }); For More details please check the sample project

Answer (score 0):

If your keys are predefined, what if your NgModel is something like:

```
$scope.NgModel = { "first" : {}, "second" : {} ... }
```

Then you can just:

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    var docparsed = JSON.parse(response);
    angular.forEach(docparsed, function (obj) {   
        $scope.NgModel[obj.key.toLocaleLowerCase()] = obj.value
    });
});
```

Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

With the AngularJS framework, use the `$http` service:

```
$http.get(url)
  .then(function(response) {
    $scope.data = response.data;
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

No need to use `jQuery.ajax`.

In the HTML, use the `ng-repeat` directive:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
    {{key}}
    <input type="text" ng-model="data[key]">
</div>
```

This will automatically display all 100+ entries in the `data` object.

To POST the data:

```
$http.post(url, $scope.data);
```